# Rails 5: can't render view for polymorphic association with namespaced model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Permission model for polymorphic association:

```
class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :permitable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  enum level: {owner: 1, view: 2, edit: 3}
end
```

In User model I have this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :allcampaigns, class_name: 'Campaigns::Allcampaigns', through: :permissions,
         source: :permitable, source_type: 'Campaigns::Allcampaigns' do

  def owner_of
    Permission.levels[:owner]
  end
end
```

and in **namespaced** Campaigns::Allcampaigns model I have:

```
module Campaigns
  class Allcampaigns < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :permissions, class_name: 'Permission', as: :permitable
  has_many :users, class_name: 'User', through: :permissions

  end
end
```

In console I can do:

```
[1] pry(main)> u = User.first
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
[2] pry(main)> u.allcampaigns
  Campaigns::Allcampaigns Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "campaign_allcampaigns".* FROM "campaign_allcampaigns" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "campaign_allcampaigns"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2  [["user_id", 1], ["permitable_type", "Campaigns::Allcampaigns"]]
```

which basically gives what I need in my index view - all campaigns for particular user.

I'm trying to implement index view with 
`@campaigns = current_user.allcampaigns`
in controller and then in view I just call this instance, but it does not work.
**I'm a bit confused, why it works in console, but not in my controller & view?** I suppose I have some silly mistake :( Thank you for any help!

**Update**

In my view I have:

```
<% @campaigns.each do |campaigns| %>
  <%= campaigns.name %>
<% end %>
```

Error I'm getting is this:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in Campaigns::Allcampaigns#index
```

and below it throws my user credentials (email, name, etc.)

**Update 2**

If anyone needs, here is how my migration for polymorphic table looks like:

```
class AddPersmissionsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :permissions do |t|
      t.belongs_to :permitable, polymorphic: true
      t.belongs_to :user, null: false
      t.integer :level, limit: 2, default: 1
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :permissions, [:permitable_id, :permitable_type]
    add_index :permissions, :level
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using `pry` to see if you can access `Campaigns::Allcampaigns ` in the controller or view? Moreover, if you can provide the exception you get, that can be very helpful to.

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter Please, see my Update above. Yes, I can do `Campaigns::Allcampaigns.all` in console and get desired result out.

Comment: I recommend using byebug, and you can add a byebug breakpoint in either controller or view code <% byebug %> to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: @ardochhigh I got it! Error was due to I had couple of more lines in index regarding roles and I should include that in view as well - basically I had to allow current_user to access rendered values. Silly me.